# Integral limit that behaves like a delta function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am having difficulty seeing why this integral reduces to $1$ or $0$, just like the delta function. In the following statement, $\Delta$ is small, whereas $R$ goes to infinity:

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits^{k_{0}+\Delta}_{k_{0}-\Delta} k\ dk\ \left\{ \frac{\sin[(K-k)R]}{K^{2}-k^{2}} \right\}=
\begin{cases}
    1; & |K-k_{0}|<\Delta\\
    0, & |K-k_{0}|>\Delta
\end{cases}  $$

**Context:**

I came across this result at the bottom of p.765 of [Morse & Feshbach's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007043316X), Methods of Theoretical Physics. The authors were trying to normalise eigenfunctions that took the form of Bessel functions and, after taking their asymptotic form, the statement reduced to this integral and they gave its result (above), which conforms with an earlier point they mentioned that such normalising integral will behave like the integral defining the delta function:

$$ \int\limits^{\Delta}_{-\Delta} \delta(z-\zeta)\ d\zeta=
\begin{cases}
    1; & |z|<\Delta\\
    0, & |z|>\Delta
\end{cases}  $$

I have tried typical methods to manipulate the integral, like integration by parts, etc, but couldn't get to the final answer above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide some context for this question? Where did you come across it? Are there any tools (theorems for instance) that you think will be useful here?  What have you tried?

Comment: @omnomnomnom I came across it at the bottom of p.765 of Morse & Feshbach's book, Methods of Theoretical Physics. They were trying to normalise eigenfunctions that took the form of Bessel functions, and after taking their asymptotic form, it reduced to this integral and they gave its result, which conforms with their earlier discussion that such normalising integral will eventually behave like the integral defining the delta function... I have basically tried typical methods to manipulate it, like integration by parts, etc, but couldn't get to the final answer...

Comment: Use the change of variable $y = k/R$ and express the result in term of the primitive of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ whose integral converges and is $=\pi$

Comment: I have updated the question and added more context to remove the "hold" imposed on it!